# Hyperref stopped working after updates

Tags: hyperref, miktex

After the latest round of updating packages with MiKTeX 4.11, the hyperref package stopped working. It throws an

```
! Emergency stop.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...color}\fi \fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \HyOpt@DriverType { (...
```

error. Here is a minimalist code example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

And here is the full log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 24.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.3.3)  3 MAR 2024 08:10
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./Hyperreftest.tex
(Hyperreftest.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count188
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count189
)
\@linkdim=\dimen140
\Hy@linkcounter=\count190
\Hy@pagecounter=\count191

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count192

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4179.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4184.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4194.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4199.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4446.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count193

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4784.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen141

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count194
\Field@Width=\dimen142
\Fld@charsize=\dimen143
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6063.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6068.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6078.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6093.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count195
\c@Item=\count196
\c@Hfootnote=\count197
)
! Extra \else.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...color}\fi \fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \HyOpt@DriverType { (...
l.4 
    
? 
! Emergency stop.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...color}\fi \fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \HyOpt@DriverType { (...
l.4 
    
End of file on the terminal!

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6808 strings out of 474422
 103422 string characters out of 5749350
 1925190 words of memory out of 5000000
 29147 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,0n,79p,240b,23s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am stumped. Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so what might be the cause?

Comment: your version of the iftex package is outdated. It should be iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests

Comment: Huh. That was strange - I _had_ updated iftex, along with all other packages I've used. But the updated package - which was displayed in MikTeX - was located at

\tex\generic\iftex\iftex.sty

while the outdated package MikTeX actually used during compiling was at:

\tex/latex/iftex\iftex.sty

I removed the old package, and now it found the right one. So, thanks - I am glad the solution was a simple one!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the OP states it is solved.